# Log background job execution time

Tags: bash, background-process, time

I have a script I execute in the background and capture all output with a command like this:

```
nohup bash -x test.sh < /dev/null > log.txt 2>&1 &
```

How can I find out how long it took to complete? If I try to use `time` after `bash -x` I get an error:

`/usr/bin/time: /usr/bin/time: cannot execute binary file`

If I try to use `acct` it doesn't seem to log the process or I can't find it.

Comment: `time` before or after `bash`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this assumes that you want the output of `time` to also go to `log.txt`, something which is not clear from your question]

Just don't use `nohup`.

`nohup` does nothing special but ignoring the `SIGHUP` signal, redirecting stdout and stderr to a file and --only in some variants, like the `nohup` from GNU coreutils-- redirecting the stdin from `/dev/null` opened in *write-only* mode.

You can easily do all that from the shell:

```
{ trap '' HUP; time bash -x your_script args ... ; } > log.txt 2>&1 0>/dev/null &
```

Or safer, if started from a script or if you don't plan to ever bring back the command to the foreground with `fg`:

```
(trap '' HUP; time bash -x your_script args ... 0>/dev/null &) > log.txt 2>&1
```

(You can omit the `0>/dev/null` if you don't care to emulate that feature of GNU nohup).

---

Of course, you can use the syntax trick from the first example with nohup too if, for some unfathomable reason, you ascribe magical properties to nohup:

```
{ time nohup bash -x your_script args ... ; } > log.txt 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Thanks. Really good answer...but what if your script takes arguments? Like a path ? Your safer approach breaks my script and I don't know why. It's a ffmpeg script that process some files in a folder

Comment: You add the arguments after `your_script arg1 arg2`, `your_script "$@"`, etc. How does your ffmpeg script break?

Comment: @Freedo maybe ffmpeg tries to open the controlling terminal for one reason or another -- try using its `-nostdin` option, or run it via `setsid ffmpeg ...`

Comment: nevermind it's working now. It was an unrelated issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could just use:

```
time yourscript.sh
```

But if that doesn't work for you, you can wrap your content of script like:

```
STARTTIME=$(date +%s)
#command block that takes time to complete...
ENDTIME=$(date +%s)
echo "It takes $($ENDTIME - $STARTTIME) seconds to complete this task..."
```

Comment: We are talking about hours, even days here but thanks. I like your approach

Answer (score 2):

Just `time` the `nohup` process:

```
$ time nohup bash -x ~/scripts/foo.sh 
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'

real    0m10.011s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.006s
```

`foo.sh` simply has `sleep 10` as an example.